# Java : Split string on same character

Tags: java, string, split

I want to split a String, using " " but `.split()` gives me empty strings in the array, which I don't want.

I tried this:

```
String[] arr = "     hello       world!     b   y    e   ".split(" ",0);
```

Output:

> ["", "", "", "", "", "hello" and so on....

Expected Output:

> ["hello","world!","b","y","e"]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, trim the string, then split by one or more whitespace (`\s+`).

```java
String string = "     hello       world!     b   y    e   ";
String[] arr = string.trim().split("\\s+");
// output: ["hello", "world!", "b", "y", "e"]
```

[String.split() reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

[Java regular expressions reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

Comment: *FYI:* Without the `trim()` call, the result would be `["", "hello", "world!", "b", "y", "e"]`. The trimming is use to eliminate the first empty string in the result. The `split()` method automatically eliminates the ending `""` value, that would be present is called with `-1` as second parameter.

Comment: @user3706706 The `+` in the regex pattern passed to `split` eliminates *repeating* spaces.

Comment: @user3706706 And then the .`split("\\s+")` splits the trimmed string by consecutive spaces.